# Convert a pandas dataframe to xml in a specified format

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'descr': ['blah', 'smthn', "yes", 'hello'],
        'num1': [0,1,5,4],
        'num2': [5,3,7,9]})

df
```

```
|category|descr|num1|num2|
|--------|-----|----|----|
|A       |blah |   0|   5|
|B       |smthn|   1|   3|
|C       |yes  |   5|   7|
|D       |hello|   4|   9|
```

I need to get it into a particular xml format, where for each row, the column name appears to the left of the value followed by an `=`

```
<MyData>
    <MyData category="A" descr="blah" num1="0" num2="5" />
    <MyData category="B" descr="smthn" num1="1" num2="3" />
    <MyData category="C" descr="yes" num1="5" num2="7" />
    <MyData category="D" descr="hello" num1="4" num2="9" />
</MyData>
```

Ultimately, the xml will contain data from many pandas dataframes, stacked atop each other like this:

```
<highestCategory fact1="5" fact2="8" >
    <lowerCategory id="69" details="abcd" >
        <someFrame>
            <someFrame col1="yes" col2="hello" />
            <someFrame col1="no" col2="bye" />
        </someFrame>
        <MyData>
            <MyData category="A" descr="blah" num1=0 num2=5 />
            <MyData category="B" descr="smthn" num1=1 num2=3 />
        </MyData>
    </lowerCategory>
    </highestCategory>
```

That is the dataframes belong to different groups and sub groups. Which makes me think organizing them into a dictionary by these groups and subgroups may be the way to go. In any case, the core issue is getting the  `<frameName colname="value" />` format

so far the closest I've manage is with `df.to_dict(orient='records')`
which yields:

```
<category>A</category>
  <descr>blah</descr>
  <num1>0</num1>
  <num2>5</num2>

  <category>B</category>
  <descr>smthn</descr>
  <num1>5</num1>
  <num2>7</num2>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in DataFrame method [`df.to_xml()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html) and its output format seems highly configurable.

### Solution (for the df -> xml part)

```
df.to_xml(root_name="MyData",  # the outermost
          row_name="MyData",   # per record
          attr_cols=df.columns.to_list(), 
          xml_declaration=False,
          index=False)
```

### Result

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(raw_str)

('<MyData>\n'
 '  <MyData category="A" descr="blah" num1="0" num2="5"/>\n'
 '  <MyData category="B" descr="smthn" num1="1" num2="3"/>\n'
 '  <MyData category="C" descr="yes" num1="5" num2="7"/>\n'
 '  <MyData category="D" descr="hello" num1="4" num2="9"/>\n'
 '</MyData>')
```

Test environment

- conda: 24.1.1

  - pandas 2.1.4
  - python: 3.12.2
- OS: Debian 12 (x86-64)